# Determining new view when switching view before events are fetched

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to fetch events every time a view is switched, and need to pass the view to the server.

However, the old view is still set at the time the events are requested from the server.

For example, the following alerts the view I am switching *from*, not the new view.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
   lazyFetching: false,
     events:
        {
           url: '/events/get-events',
           extraParams: function(){ 
              alert(calendar.view.type);
           }
        }
     }
```

Switch views in the following codepen

https://codepen.io/bestrong89/pen/RwPVmdY?editors=0010

Any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: "need to pass the view to the server"...why, out of interest? What would the server do differently, depending on the view? The view generally only changes the amount of days visible, or the layout of them. The events which occur on those days is the same in all cases.

Comment: Anway, event rendering and view rendering are asynchronous operations. AFAIK you can't guarantee that the view will have updated before the AJAX request is launched to fetch the events. So you're going to have trouble achieving this, I would suspect.

Comment: We are using list year to just list events for a current account, so if the view is listYear, I just have the events returned for the current account.

Comment: A bit of a hack, but I am listening for a mouse down on the view change button, and setting a flag if the button is listYear. Works for now.

Comment: Ok. Just beware that if you have navLinks enabled, for example, that can also change the view. So there might be other ways than just the main buttons.

Comment: Right. Thank you!